# Как импортировать библиотеку .Net Core из кода Python?

Tags: python, dll, .net-core

Необходимо импортировать DLL библиотеку, написанную для платформы .Net Core, для использования ее классов и методов в коде Python. Как это можно сделать и можно ли вообще? Интересует только CPython

Comment: я подобное только для с++ кода делал: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/using_custom_dll Только пример простейший -- несколько методов в dll

Comment: Навряд ли что-то выйдет без IronPython. Для нативного C++ все гораздо проще: для Си совместимых функций есть ctypes, а для C++ 11 есть pybind11. Про .NET если только CLR руками поднимать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, это не возможно. dll файлы .Net Core это сборки(Assembly), а не динамически подключаемые библиотеки. Так как сборка содержит IL для виртуальной машины CLR, а не нативный код, её невозможно подключить к программе на Python.

Answer (score 0):

Костыль, но может быть полезно: [MetaCall](https://github.com/metacall/core)